# Show a Div first and then Submit on second click of button in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with multiple divs with same names (`full-width`). They all are on the same level. One of them is hidden (with a class `hide`). What I want is that if I select Submit, it should not submit, first hide all the brother divs of the hidden div (in this case `full-width`) and unhide the one with the class `hide`.

Now when I press again, it should just submit the Form.

JSFiddle is here:- http://jsfiddle.net/xmqvx/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also take advantage of JavaScript's closures like so, to avoid having your behavior be dependent on your UI:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var alreadyClicked = false;
    $("#submit-this").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (alreadyClicked) {
            $('#this-form').submit();
        } else {
            $('.full-width').hide();
            $('.hide').show();
            alreadyClicked = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff. You just made it so easy.

Answer (score 7):

Your code had a couple issues:

1. You used `event.preventDefault` but passed `event` in as `e` - should be `e.preventDefault`
2. Your ID selector targeted an ID that didnt exist (changed to `#submit-this`)

The working code:

```
$("#submit-this").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(".full-width").hasClass("hide")) {
        $(".full-width").hide();
        $(".full-width.hide").removeClass("hide").show();
    } else {
        alert("Submitting");
        $("#this-form").submit();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xmqvx/4/

Comment: Thank you. I should be more cautious :)

Comment: @Steve -- No problem, be sure to accept an answer if it accomplished what you were looking for,.